# What is this icon from shell32.dll

Tags: icons

I'm curious what this icon represents. I imagine it's an ancient disk reader. Anyone know what is it?

[image]

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Looks like a Compact Flash to USB reader. Specifically, those finger grips on the side looks like an exact match for the [Sandisk Imagemate (SDDR-09)](https://www.cnet.com/products/sandisk-imagemate-usb-card-reader-usb-series/):

[image: A pic of a Sandisk Imagemate (SDDR-09)]

I believe the same form factor was used for the SanDisk USB SmartMedia Reader (SDDR-09-01) which used for the now obsoleted [SmartMedia card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SmartMedia) format which were cards that were as flat as SD cards but a bit larger in size.

And there was even an older serial version with the model number SDDR-01; different data connection but same core form factor. But the size of that slot looks like a dead ringer for a Compact Flash card reader from ye olden days of about 15 years ago.